# Why is my UITableView not being set?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

I checked using the debbuger in the viewDidLoad method and tracerTableView is 0x0 which i assume means it is nil. I don't understand. I should go ahaed say yes I have already checked my nib file and yes all the connections are correct. Here is the header file and the begging of the .m.

**.h file**

```
@interface TrackerListController : UITableViewController <AddPackageDelegate>{  

    // The mutable (modifiable) dictionary days holds all the data for the days tab  
    NSMutableArray *trackerList;  
    UITableView *tracerTableView;  
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *trackerList;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView. *tracerTableView;

//The addPackage: method is invoked when the user taps the addbutton created at runtime.

-(void) addPackage : (id) sender;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
@implementation TrackerListController

@synthesize trackerList, tracerTableView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Package Tracker";  

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem; 

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addPackage:)];

    // Set up the Add custom button on the right of the navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    [addButton release];  
    // Release the addButton from memory since it is no longer needed

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The table is already an IBOutlet. You can specify those on 2 places, first in the declaration or on the @property line. So that seems ok.

The tableview is connected to the tracerTableView property in the .h file and you synthesize them correctly.

How do you load the ViewController. Do you init it with NibName? Could you maybe post that code too? Because just initializing it as:

```
TrackerListController* viewControl = [[TrackerListController alloc] init];
```

Doesnt seem to work when you want to use a nib. Try using this instead:

```
TrackerListController* viewControl = [[TrackerListController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"trackerListController" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a typo. The following line:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView. *tracerTableView;
```

should be:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tracerTableView;
```

To be clear, in the header file, I would declare the table view to be an Interface Builder outlet:

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tracerTableView;
```

After doing this, to double-check, I would also make sure the File's Owner (the view controller) in your XIB is wired up *from* the File's Owner *to* the Table View.